# Error in UseMethod("ranef") : no applicable method for 'ranef' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Tags: r, lm, lme4

What kind of variable should the random effect be if i use this code:

```
lme(minpH ~ `rumination (min/d)`*`VET EIWIT ratio`, 
    data = phase_data_compleet, random.effects(experiment))
```

if the random effect variable is numeric, double of character it gives an error, maybe i do something else wrong. my purpose is to run a mixed effect model with minpH as dependent variable and rumination, VET EIWIT RATIO as independet variables, experiment is the random effect, because the data is collected during several experiments in the past.

If I use the code without the random effect, it works:

```
lm(minpH ~ `rumination (min/d)`*`VET EIWIT ratio`, data = phase_data_compleet)
```

like to hear your suggestion about what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```r
lme(minpH ~ `rumination (min/d)`*`VET EIWIT ratio`, 
    random = ~ 1|experiment,
    data = phase_data_compleet)
```

?  `experiment` should ideally be a factor, but it's conceivable that `lme` will automatically convert it for you.

`random.effects()` is a complete red herring: it's a synonym for `ranef()`, which is used *after* you fit the model to extract information about group-level deviations from the population estimates.